# Unity 2D 2020: How do I get an animation to continue playing on a paused timeline?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The timeline is triggered upon entering the box collider. The timeline plays, and any animations that are slotted in before the signal emitter play, but they paused when the timeline pauses it. They currently play the base animation that they have in place. I need the animation to loop a speech animation instead of pausing it upon reaching the signal emitter that pauses the timeline.

Code on timeline pause is below for anyone that might need it.

`public class PauseTimeline : MonoBehaviour
{
private PlayableDirector director;

```
void Start()
{
    director = GetComponent<PlayableDirector>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        PlayTime();
    }
}

public void PauseTime()
    {
        director.Pause();
    }

    public void PlayTime()
    {
        director.Play();
    }
```

}`

I've tried searching on the Unity website, but they only cover how to stop the animations? How do I keep animations playing upon pausing the timeline? I'm considering trying to have one GameObject with the speech animation and another GameObject with the basic idle animation, and just using a control track to turn them  on and off based on what I need. But I don't think this will work?

Answer (score 0):

In the inspector, select the "Update Method" as "Unscaled Game Time" on the Playable Director

[Documentation Playable Director](https://docs.unity.cn/2019.2/Documentation/Manual/class-PlayableDirector.html)